# EntitySet.Last() is not the latest added element?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an entityset in Linq to SQL, let's say a person with multiple addresses. Then with this code

```
person.Addresses.Add(address);
person.Addresses.Last(). ... // Not the one just added!
```

Last() is some address, not the one added last. Accessing the one added on the previous line with

```
person.Addresses.Where(x => x.UniqueId == address.UniqueId).Single(). ...
```

works, but this seems a bit strange to me.

UniqueId is a GUID and is the primary key of the Address table. Is that the cause? Is Last() returning the address with the biggest GUID and not the last one added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DbSet` is not simply a collection of entities so what you have here is effectively two database queries.

```
INSERT INTO Addresses ...

SELECT ... FROM Addresses ...
```

The two are not linked in any way. If you really want to get the most recently added item then you should either:

1. Keep the value(s) of the primary key for the item you have just inserted and use that to retrieve the entity:

   ```
   person.Addresses.Add(address);
   var id = address.Id;
   //snip
   var address = person.Addresses.Single(a => a.Id == id);
   ```
2. Order the `DbSet` and then take the last one:

   ```
   //Assuming the Id column is auto-incrementing
   var address = person.Addresses.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).Take(1).Single();

   //Assuming you have a date added column for example:
   var address = person.Addresses.OrderByDescending(a => a.DateAdded).Take(1).Single();
   ```